# How to add disks to existing RAID-6

Tags: raid, drac

I'd like to double the size of an existing RAID-6. It currently contains 12 disks and I added 12 more. When I go through the IDRAC interface, I can only see options to add them as global hotspare. I thought I could just add the disks to the array and then enlarge the partition, all without losing data.

I'm no expert on RAID so maybe I'm mistaken. I've seen that there are more RAID management options in the BIOS than in IDRAC, so maybe it needs to be done through the BIOS...? If that matters, the controller is a MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 Invader / PERC H730P and IDRAC is version 8.

Comment: Although you *can* have a 24 disk R6 I'd advise against it, try a R60 instead.

Comment: To expand on @Chopper3's comment: With today's disk sizes, in case of a drive failure rebuilding a 24-disk traditional RAID6 array will take a huge amount of time. Worse: Your I/O performance will be abysmal during the entire process. With two striped 12-disk RAID6 arrays, you will "lose" the equivalent of two extra drives worth of storage space, but in case of drive failure you'll "only" have to rebuild a single 12-drive array.

Answer (score 1):

```
perccli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid6 option=add drives=32:7-9
```

you need online migrate,dell's perccli will help you.

my chinese wiki notes:
https://wiki2.xbits.net:4430/hardware:lsi:%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8perccli%E5%B0%86raid5%E5%8D%87%E7%BA%A7%E4%B8%BAraid6